# Проблема с расположением checkbox вместе с текстом в одну линию выведенные из бд

Tags: php

Не могу найти решение проблемы связанные, уже пытался сам экспериментировать с кодом. Необходимо именно в PHP коде, чтобы все `checkbox` стояли в одну линию, а не как показано на представленном изображении. Искал в интернете, ответа не нашел, всё решения используют стили, а мне нужно именно использовать php код, чтобы позже можно было определять какие были checkbox нажаты или нет и по некоторым другим причинам, именно эта реализация нужна.

Вот такой код:

```
<ul class="checkbox-brand">

<?php

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category WHERE type='mobile'",$link); 

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        do
        {
            echo '<li><input type="checkbox"  name="brand[]" align="center" value="'.$row["id"].'" id="checkbrend'.$row["id"].'" /><label for="checkbrend'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["brand"].'</label></li>';

        }
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result));
    }

?>

</ul>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: к пхп, ваш вопрос отношения не имеет, все правильно советуют использовать стили

Comment: Спасибо я уже нашел ответ, только пока не понятно будет ли работать забирание значений для того, чтобы отслеживать информацию или нет, а с этим мы уже позже разберёмся.